# Color each half of a disc differently

Tags: graphics, color

Given a simple graphics object like a disc in black:

```
Graphics[Disk[]]
```

Is it possible to split the disc in the middle, i.e. color each half differently e.g. left half in black and right half in red?

Comment: See the three-argument form of `Disk` in the documentation. Alternatively, construct it from `Polygon`s (see `CirclePoints`).

Comment: Also `DiskSegment`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Graphics[{
  Black, DiskSegment[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}],
  Red, DiskSegment[{0, 0}, 1, {3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2}]
  }]
```

[image: disk]

EDIT: `DiskSegment` was introduced in MMA 10.2. Alternative code that works in previous versions is simply...

```
Graphics[{
  Black, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}],
  Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2}]
  }]
```

Comment: Thank you! But it seems, that the DiskSegment function doesn't exist in mathematica 10.1? Which version are u using?

Comment: @holistic Please see my edited answer. I have just learned about this use of `Disk`.

Comment: Great, thank you!!